# does every react project started with the same react app that comes with spinning react logo or is there some other way to remove boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs

does every react project started with the same react app that comes with spinning react logo or is there some other way to remove boilerplate? I want to create a learning project with which I can start learning react hooks and all with YouTube tutorials and other methods, the problem is I use `npx create-react-app my-app` to install dependencies, now when I try to remove CSS files or any other files that I wont need, it throws an error in react, so my question is can I install dependencies without the classic react spinning wheel logo and other things to keep it all clean?

Comment: See this section from the create-react-app docs, ["You might not need a toolchain"](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#you-might-not-need-a-toolchain) would be a good place to start. create-react-app is, itself, a template so it is going to include boilerplate. FWIW, I think you should stick with create-react-app if you're learning. If you post the errors you are getting, we can help you resolve them

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to remove the imports for the files you deleted.

Comment: What is "reportwebvitals.js"? Because I cannot find any "imports" of it

Comment: it's a function in your index.js file